# XHTML Validation problem within Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, w3c

So, I read the W3C validation FAQ about why some javascript causes validation errors but didn't seem to find an answer regarding my problem.

If you try to validate http://www.proskimboarding.com/codingtest/Public/registration.php

you'll receive a bunch of errors within the javascript code... anyone know of a solution for this? (mainly involving ampersands)

Comment: Not getting errors in FF or IE8.

Comment: I'm talking about if you validate the document through the W3C validator

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that worked for you. Just click the checkmark next to your chosen answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your ampersands need to be `&amp;` instead of just `&` when outside of javascript, inside javascript you need to use this style with your script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

alert("My Code here");

//]]>
</script>
```

**Update:**  Tested this with your code, it solves 12/13 errors, the last is just not having a character encoding specified in the file, which is minor.

Comment: Is that exactly how it's written?

Comment: That works, thanks. I'll research more on exactly what it does later on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your & need to be encoded to &amp;